# Referencing object sent to a function in React component

Tags: reactjs

In the following component, if I try to access the properties of myData object inside the `getMessage()` function, using `myData.gender` I'm getting an undefined error.

If I try `myData.myData.gender` it works. Why is that?

When I inspect myData coming into the `getMessage()` function, I see that it's an object and it contains a myData object in it. I'm confused why myData object is placed inside of another object.

Interestingly, inside my component I can access the properties directly as you can see in the line `<div>Hello {myData.firstName}</div>`

Here's my simple React component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({myData}) => {

    return(

        <div>Hello {myData.firstName}</div>
        <div>

            {getMessage(myData)}

        </div>
    );
};

const getMessage(myData) => {

   let output = "";

   if(myData.Gender == "m") {
      output = "<span>Enjoy the football game tonight!</span>";
   }
   else {
      output = "<span>Enjoy your roses!</span>";
   }

   return output;

}

ChannelContent.propTypes = {
    myData: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

you've a typo either in your question or in code:

try `myData.gender === 'm'` instead of `myData.Gender == "m"`

Comment: why downvote? in your code, you're trying to check `(myData.Gender == "m")` while in your question you were talking about `myData.gender` with lowercase `g`.